# Memory issue when i implement Snapchat-like doodle on picture (details included)

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, core-graphics

I try to implement Snapchat-like feature allowing user draws things on taken picture.

Basically, i have two views. (here some codes)

```
UIImageView *imageView; //holding the taken picture (original image)
UIImageView *drawingView; //the view on which all drawing happens

/* this is the action triggered by gesture recognizer */
- (void)drawingViewDidPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    CGPoint currentDraggingPosition = [sender locationInView:_drawingView];

    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        _prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
    }

    if(sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        [self drawLine:_prevDraggingPosition to:currentDraggingPosition];
    }
    _prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
}

-(void)drawLine:(CGPoint)from to:(CGPoint)to
{
    CGSize size = _drawingView.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat strokeWidth = MAX(1, _widthSlider.value * 65);
    UIColor *strokeColor = _strokePreview.backgroundColor;

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    _drawingView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

/* this is the method to build final image, I overlay the image from drawing on top of the imageView */
- (UIImage*)buildImage
{
    CGSize _originalImageSize = imageView.image.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_originalImageSize, NO, 0.0);

    [imageView.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [drawingView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _originalImageSize.width, _originalImageSize.height)];

    UIImage *tmp = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return tmp;
}
```

When buildImage() is called, my app crashed with memory warning. I'm testing on **iPhone 4s** (512 ram) and full-screen photo has resolution 2448x3264. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the UIImage class reference:

> You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x 1024 in size. Besides the large amount of memory such an image would consume, you may run into problems when using the image as a texture in OpenGL ES or when drawing the image to a view or layer. This size restriction does not apply if you are performing code-based manipulations, such as resizing an image larger than 1024 x 1024 pixels by drawing it to a bitmap-backed graphics context. In fact, you may need to resize an image in this manner (or break it into several smaller images) in order to draw it to one of your views.

I would suggest working on a much smaller image.